# Can an Excel cell formula refer to a UserForm control?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, formula, userform

I have a UserForm with text boxes that are already bound to certain worksheet cells through the ControlSource property. I need to run a calculation between two of these bound values and have the result end up in a third worksheet cell. I know there are numerous ways this can be done, but I'm wondering whether there's some way to do this as a formula in the worksheet cell that references the UserForm control values. For example, I would like to be able to put a formula in cell C3 that goes something like

= UserForm1.TextBox1.Value * UserForm1.TextBox2.Value

but I haven't found any reference that addresses using worksheet cell formulas to fetch values directly from UserForm controls. (And no, in this case I can't just reference the bound cells by plugging something like "= A1 * B2" into cell C3. **This question is specifically about whether it's feasible to reference a UserForm control from within a worksheet cell formula.**)
Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions.

Comment: *Why* can't you just use `=A1*B2` in `C3`?

Comment: Because the bound cell references are going to change, but I want the results from the calculation to always end up in the same cell. I can pass the addresses of the bound cells when they change and rewrite the formula in C3 every time, if I have to, but it would be a lot easier to just reference the values in the controls themselves.

Comment: I've shown a UDF in my answer, but I still think you can just use formulas without needing to read the control properties. If the cells are going to change, then used named cells (thereby abstracting away the absolute addresses). Have the controls bind to the named ranges, and have your formula s refer to the names.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to refer to the property of an ActiveX control on a worksheet, is via a user-defined-function, such as:

```
Public Function GetTextBoxValue(TextBoxName As String) As String
  On Error GoTo 0
  Dim o As OLEObject
  Set o = Sheet1.OLEObjects(TextBoxName)
  On Error Resume Next
  If Not o Is Nothing Then
    GetTextBoxValue = o.Object.Text
  End If
End Function
```

Then call the function from a cell, like: `=GetTextBoxValue("TextBox1")`

Comment: I think you meant `Sheet1.OLEObjects(TextBoxName)` instead of `Sheet1.OLEObjects("TextBox1")`.

Comment: indeed - half a refactor. fixed now